# How to fetch data from the provided link?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Actually I got this link from the api and this is the image I want to show in the flutter application.

Status Code = 200 so successful extraction of JSON format is done.
Then I decoded the JSON body and after that when I use that link to extract image then error flashed out.

I used:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Enjoy Memes"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Image.network('https://i.redd.it/0qyu4z44zza71.jpg')
    );
  }
}
```

but it didn't work. This is the error I got:

[image]

How can I deal with this? Need to use html then.

Comment: Have you tried loading some other images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to display the images from another domain. For being able to display your images from any other domain or from firebase Storage on a Flutter web page you have to configure your data for [CORS](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors).

1. Open the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), select your project and start a cloud terminal session by clicking the `>_` icon button in the top navbar.
2. Click the open editor button (pencil icon), then create the `cors.json` file.
3. Run `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://your-bucket`

The `cors.json` file should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

I set the origin to `*` which means that every website can display your images. But you can also insert the domain of your website there to restrict access.

If you need more information: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors